# Arc4Random in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking to use the arc4random function in swift code, what would be the equivalent to this line of Objective-C code?

```
if (arc4random() % 2 == 0) {

// Swing 1

    }else{

// Swing 2

}
```

Comment: It'd be the same. You need to import Foundation.

Comment: Please prefer `arc4random_uniform(2) == 0` instead, in both Swift and ObjC. The `%` form only works when the RHS is a power-of-two (it is true in this case, but you don't always choose just between two numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Foundation

if arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 {
    // Swing 1
}
else{
    // Swing 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? Swing 1 : Swing 2
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!